# Creating database backup from ASP page

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

One of my client has ASP site. Now he want to transfer the site to a different hosting. Unfortunately I have only FTP of the live site. Could any one please advise about how to create database backup using ASP pages.

Comment: What kind of DB you use? Don't you have any ways to access the DB? Or even to ask the hosting to provide an export or backup of the DB?

Comment: Is is Mssql server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in the worst case you could always do the Brute Force create new Backup on-click method:

```
<%Dim SQL, Conn, Database
Database = //Your database-Path
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open("/*Connection-String*/" + Database, 3,1)

SQL = "CREATE DATABASE [BackupDB]; BACKUP [Database] TO [BackupDB];"
conn.Execute(SQL)
%>
Database was backed up to "BackupDB"
```

but that should be avoided at all cost, because it is very unsafe and might as well shut down your whole system, if done wrong...

Best would be as @ppeterka 66 mentioned, that you ask your hosting provider to backup your database and send it to you.